# Start using time for product (License type)

Tags: magento, date, using

In checkout cart mornitor, i added a datepicker for earch product in cart to allow cusommer selecting start using date (within 1 month from now).
I want to save this datepicker to onepage when click place-order. It will save to order.
I already create attribute in eav_attribute.
In config.xml i use this code:

```
<events>

            <controller_action_predispatch_checkout_cart_index >
                <observers>
                    <licensetime_observer>
                        <class>licensetime/observer</class>
                        <method>saveLicensetime</method>
                    </licensetime_observer>
                </observers>
            </controller_action_predispatch_checkout_cart_index>

        </events>
```

And observer i was try to var_dump but start_date is null

```
public function saveLicensetime($observer)
    {

        $event = $observer->getEvent();
        $product = $event->getProduct();
        $quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/type_onepage')->getQuote();
        $licenseStartDate = $quote->getLicense_start_date();
        if (!$licenseStartDate) {
            $licenseStartDate = date ("Y-m-d H:i:s", floor(time()/86400)*86400);
        }
        //var_dump($quote); die("aaaaaaaaaaa");

    }
```

In cart/item/defaul.phtml datepicker code:

```
<label for="license_start_date"><?php echo $this->__('Start Date') ?> :</label>
    <input name="cart[<?php echo $_item->getId() ?>][license_start_date]" readonly="true" id="license_start_date<?php echo $_item->getProductId(); ?>" value="<?php echo $this->getLicenseStartTime($_item->getId()) ?>" class="date-picker" />
    <label for="license_end_date"><?php echo $this->__('End Date') ?> :</label>
    <input readonly="true" name="cart[<?php echo $_item->getId() ?>][license_end_date]" id="license_end_date<?php echo $_item->getProductId(); ?>" value="<?php echo $this->getLicenseEndTime($_item->getId()) ?>"></input>
```

I'm trying this article but no luck!

> [Magento change Custom Option value before adding it to cart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9334115/magento-change-custom-option-value-before-adding-it-to-cart)

Sorry, my E not well!

Comment: It may be easier to include this datepicker on the actual product page as a custom option and have it saved with the item in the quote. That way the datepicker will follow through automatically right through the checkout and will be saved in the order automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After few days ago, i'm hard-working and know that:
- Override app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Model/Cart.php and edit function like that:

```
    public function updateItems($data)
 {
     Mage::dispatchEvent('checkout_cart_update_items_before', array('cart'=>$this, 'info'=>$data));

     foreach ($data as $itemId => $itemInfo) {

         $item = $this->getQuote()->getItemById($itemId);
         if (!$item) {
             continue;
         }

         if (!empty($itemInfo['remove']) || (isset($itemInfo['qty']) && $itemInfo['qty']=='0')) {
             $this->removeItem($itemId);
             continue;
         }

         $qty = isset($itemInfo['qty']) ? (float) $itemInfo['qty'] : false;
         if ($qty > 0) {
             $item->setQty($qty);
         }

     /* Start: Custom code added for license start date */
     if(!empty($itemInfo['license_start_date'])) {

        $write = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write');

        # make the frame_queue active
        $query = "UPDATE `sales_flat_quote_item` SET license_start_date = '".$itemInfo['license_start_date']."' where item_id = $itemId";
$write->query($query);

        $item->setLicense_start_date($itemInfo['license_start_date']);
     }
     /* End: Custom code added for licensee start date */

     }

     Mage::dispatchEvent('checkout_cart_update_items_after', array('cart'=>$this, 'info'=>$data));
     return $this;
 }
```

and copy app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/Items/Abstract.php to local (app/code/local/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/Items/Abstract.php) and add this function:

```
public function getLicense_start_date($item) {
        $itemId = $item->getId();

        $write = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write');

        $query = "SELECT q.* FROM `sales_flat_order_item` o
        LEFT JOIN `sales_flat_quote_item` q on o.quote_item_id = q.item_id
        WHERE o.item_id = $itemId";

        # For older versions of Magento
/*      $query = "SELECT q.* FROM `sales_order_entity_int` o
        LEFT JOIN `sales_flat_quote_item` q on o.value = q.entity_id
        WHERE o.entity_id = $itemId AND o.attribute_id = 343";       */     

        $res = $write->query($query);

        while ($row = $res->fetch() ) {
            if(key_exists('itemcomment',$row)) {
                echo nl2br($row['itemcomment']);
            }
        }
    }
```

To add the license time column to the items edit the .phtml file below:
app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/view/items.phtml (you can add you theme in adminhtml to edit)

Adding header for items to make it look like below:

```
<tr class="headings">
<th><?php echo $this->helper('sales')->__('Product') ?></th>
<th><?php echo $this->helper('sales')->__('Licens Time') ?></th>
<th><?php echo $this->helper('sales')->__('Item Status') ?></th>
```

And adding Column with comments. app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/view/items/renderer/default.phtml
Add a column for item comments juts before status columns to make it look a like below.

```
<td><?php echo $this->getLicense_start_date($_item) ?></td> <!-- New column added for item comments -->
<td class="a-center"><?php echo $_item->getStatus() ?></td>
```

Note that: In your theme, for the file: template/checkout/cart.phtml
Add the new heading along with other heading for cart items and in the file: template/checkout/cart/item/default.phtml use datepicker to selected date with code like below:

```
<td class="a-center">
<input type="text" name="cart[<?php echo $_item->getId() ?>][license_start_date]" rows="3" cols="20"><?php echo $_item->getLicense_start_date() ?></input>
</td>
```